# Rails JSON Deserialization Invalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, deserialization

Rails JSON deserialization seems to be creating invalid JSON when serializing errors. For example, the following snippet appears correct as a hash but incorrect as json:

```
@model.errors
# { message: ["it too short (minimum is 2 characters)", "contains inappropriate content"] }

@model.errors.to_json
# {
#  message: "is too short (minimum is 2 characters)",
#  message: "contains inapproriate content",
# }
```

Am I incorrect in understanding that keys must be unique? Thanks.

Comment: I can't reproduce your example, I've got valid json (nice array) created.

Comment: @apneadiving The project is running on a slightly outdated version of Rails I just realized (3.0.3). After updating to 3.0.9 it appears to be fixed.

Comment: @apneadiving Thanks for the confirmation that it was just my version!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with an outdated version of Rails (3.0.3). Updated to 3.0.9 and everything worked.